# HTTP GET Request using HTML/JavaScript+JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I am trying to make a HTTP GET request from my HTML page. The backend of the app is designed using PHP and the Laravel 4 framework (for PHP).

The backend of the API is working. I have tested it using the `curl` command on my Mac's terminal

```
curl -v http://localhost:8888/l4/public/api/v1/getLeaderboard
```

I am now making the front-end using HTML/JavaScript. This is what I have

```
<script>
        function sampleFunction(){
            alert("hello world ");
        }
        function loadLeaderboard(){
            $.get("http://localhost:8888/l4/public/api/v1/getLeaderboard",function(data,status){
                    alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
             });
        }
</script>
```

And I am trying to load it as soon as the page is opened: However, nothing happens. How do I fix this ?

```
<body onload=loadLeaderboard()>
```

**EDIT**: This is the error message I am seeing in the console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

EDIT 2 : I solved the above problem by providing the full path of the jquery file i.e. http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js. Initially I was not using http://

The error message I am currently getting is:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8888/l4/public/api/v1/getLeaderboard. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin
```

Comment: Try attaching the event in JavaScript when the DOM is ready, not in the markup.

Comment: I tried `<button onclick=loadLeaderboard()> Click Me </button>`. Same problem. Nothing happens

Comment: Did you see any message in the console?

Comment: Is the page that does the query running on `localhost:8888`? If not, you're running afoul of the AJAX same-origin policy.

Comment: Look at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/#jqxhr-object and use fail, done, always methods.

Comment: @elclanrs Since his function doesn't access any DOM elements, why does it need to wait for DOM ready?

Comment: @Barmar: I'm guessing OP's script is loaded in the body.

Comment: Hmm, I just looked at the console. It failed to load the jqery library

Comment: From where you are running your page? some web server or file:// c:// etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue which was resolved by editing the backend code so that it allows Cross origin requests. To do this, I opened the `routes.php` file in the framework and added this line to the top of the page

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear whether your function is defined before or after the body onload event. Also, for debugging purposes I would recommend firing this test with a click event on a link. This way you have some time to open up the JavaScript console in your browser so that you can see what is happening at the time the the test is run. Give the code below a shot.

On the PHP end, make sure the data you are returning is json encoded.

```
$(function() {

    var loadLeaderboard = function (){
        $.get("http://localhost:8888/l4/public/api/v1/getLeaderboard",function(data){
            alert("Data: " + data);
        });
    };

    $('body').on('click', '.test-link', function() {
        loadLetterboard();
    });

});
```

Comment: This is the error message in the console `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

Comment: That means that jQuery is not loading properly. Check the status of the GET request for jQuery. If you're using Firefox with Firebug you can click on the NET tab and then click on JS and then reload the page. I am guessing you will see a 404 error. If you are hot-linking to jQuery from the Google Ajax CDN you may be using a link that does not specify a protocol (it doesn't start with http: it starts with //) This may not work on your local machine depending upon whether or not the page is being served by an HTTP server and how that server is configured. Try adding http:

Comment: Yes, that solved one problem. I just made an edit to the post. The new error is - `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8888/l4/public/api/v1/getLeaderboard. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin`

Comment: Access-Control-Allow-Origin this occurs when u try to access from local to any cross domain url's... try using $.AJAX insted of $.GET

Answer (score 0):

Origin null is the local file system, so that suggests that you're loading the HTML page that does the load call via a file:/// URL (e.g., just double-clicking it in a local file browser or similar). Different browsers take different approaches to applying the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) to local files.

My guess is that you're seeing this using Chrome. Chrome's rules for applying the SOP to local files are very tight, it disallows even loading files from the same directory as the document. So does Opera. Some other browsers, such as Firefox, allow limited access to local files. But basically, using ajax with local resources isn't going to work cross-browser.

If you're just testing something locally that you'll really be deploying to the web, rather than use local files, install a simple web server and test via http:// URLs instead. That gives you a much more accurate security picture.